# is this powdery mildew growing on my young carrots?

Tags: carrots, mildew

I can't tell if this is powdery mildew as it doesn't seem powdery and is instead concentrated blobs of white. It also doesn't come off when I wipe it, unlike the videos I've seen. The leaves are still young and haven't had time to fully develop either. any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Hi Craig, the way this site works, its probably better if you put the poop part as an answer.  :-)

Comment: ah thankyou, I didn't know you could answer your own topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I may have figured it out (unless it comes back). but you'll never believe this! I put other plants outside for a while after finding this issue. I came back to those plants several hours later to find a bird pooped all over them... I cleaned them up with a paper towel and that got me thinking about the carrots. So I wiped them up the same way, with a paper towel and the white came off! It's silly I know, but I'm afraid to say it may have just been some bird poop....